# How can I improve my Touch AC outside of increasing my Dex Mod?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, touch-attacks, armor-class

I'm currently playing a LVl5 Caster Druid in a PVP arena, where the other players are quite fond of blaster type characters, and I tend not to last more then 2 or 3 rounds.  While I'd like any specific way to increase my Touch AC for this character, I am also contemplating re-rolling a Dex based character to provide the highest possible TAC.

Outside of a higher DEX mod, what other options will I have to increase my TAC and provide further survivability against Blasters?

Starting character level is 5, with average WPL progression, starting at 10,000gp. A houserule states that no one item can cost more then 50% of WPL guidelines.

Opponents so far seem very fond of Scorching Ray, and Reach Metamagic on various touch spells such as Frigid Touch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**To directly make yourself harder to hit with ranged touch attacks**

- Get behind cover (which can include cover you create, teammates, or opponents)
- Engage their ally in melee (negated by Precise Shot feat on the attacker)
- Kneel or drop prone
- It's technically raising your Dex mod, but cast *cat's grace*.
- Get concealment (possibly from a spell)
- Gain a deflection or dodge bonus to your AC (from your own or an ally's spell or ability)

**To make ranged attacks harder or impossible for your foes**

- Get your allies in melee with them (or summon allies in melee with them)
- Get yourself in melee with them (blaster-casters probably won't like being in melee with a Druid)
- Break their line of sight completely or gain total concealment
- Distract, blind, dazzle, fatigue, sicken, or entangle them (with spells)
- Intimidate them (inflict the shaken condition)
- Disarm them or break their weapon
- Knock them prone / trip them
- Manipulate the wind conditions (or just find a way to fight on a windy day)

**Some useful [Druid spells](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/spell-lists-and-domains/spell-lists---druid) of third level or lower for your situation**

- Orisons:

  *flare*
- First level:

  *summon minor ally, mudball, entangle, flare burst, burning disarm, expeditious excavation, nereid's grace, thunderstomp, ray of sickening*

  Best in class: *expeditious excavation* can grant total cover, *thunderstomp* is a ranged trip, *entangle* penalizes ranged attacks twice, and *mudball* can completely blind a target.
- Second level:

  *burst of radiance, euphoric cloud, fog cloud, fury of the sun, gust of wind, gusting sphere, ice slick, pox pustules, soften earth and stone, sickening entanglement, summon swarm, tar ball, warp wood*

  Best in class:  *ice slick* is an area-effect repeated trip, *pox pustules* penalizes ranged attacks twice while *sickening entanglement* penalizes them three times, but *soften earth and stone* and *warp wood* have ways to make ranged attacks impossible.
- Third level:

  *aqueous orb, ash storm, burrow, cloak of winds, sleet storm, wind wall*

  Best in class:  *ash storm* and *sleet storm* both completely block vision and hamper movement, while *burrow* lets you get underground where you can't be targeted.

If your GM allows really, really cheap spells that are supposed to be race-restricted:

*aboleth's lung* will very quickly suffocate a target to death.

Comment: Your lack of *invisibility* is disturbing. Cast vanish (1st level) or invisibility (2nd), buff yourself up. Then cast blink if you have access to it (3rd) and start blasting with area spells (flaming sphere is particularly effective to use while invisible).

Comment: @ShadowKras I don't see those on the druid spell list. Can you suggest a way a druid can gain access to those spells?

Comment: That's some great options for Ranged combat, and I'll definitely be using some of them.  What I was really looking for were specific ways of increasing my TAC, so that I can still play offensively after buffing up, and not be blasted by a couple of scorching rays.

Comment: @HeyICanChan potions :) They are 1st, 2nd and 3rd level spells. A vanish potion will last for a round and costs only 50 gp, while a potion of invisibility will last for 3 minutes and worth every coin in keeping you alive.